# Sorting CSS properties into an arbitrary order?

Tags: css

I would like to programmatically sort all declarations/properties (not the declaration blocks themselves, but the individual declarations inside each block) in a style sheet into an arbitrary order.

I have been able to find several methods online for sorting declarations alphabetically, or reverse alphabetically, or even by string length, but this is unhelpful for me because those sorting methods are essentially meaningless. Instead, i would like to sort according to the way i personally think of CSS rules, which places structural declarations first, followed by text declarations, followed by background declarations, and so on.

As an example, in case that's not clear, suppose i have a style sheet that contains the following:

```
#someid {
    font-size: 200%;
    background-color: #000000;
    color: #ffffff;
    padding: 4px 8px;
}
```

I would like to be able to sort this into something like:

```
#someid {
    padding: 4px 8px;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 200%;
    background-color: #000000;
}
```

Does anyone know of a tool that would allow me to create sort of a template that defines the exact order i want the properties to be in, and then apply it to achieve something like the above? Or would this be easy to do via, say, a TextMate bundle?

Hope this isn't a ridiculous question. :) Cheers!

Comment: +1 as I think this is a pretty good question and in no way ridiculous.

Comment: It’s completely ridiculous, but I’d love something like that too :)

Comment: It's not really "sorting" if it's in an arbitrary order, is it? How would you programmatically describe the sort algorithm to accomplish what you want?

Comment: The dichotomous situation is that you want to apply rules to an arbitrary process...

Comment: @Matt It's user sorting. You only need to supply a map of priorities (or weights) for the sorting to make sense.

Comment: @Matt Ball, @Mr. Disappointment: His question makes sense `"sort all declarations/properties in a style sheet into an arbitrary order"`.  arbitrary = `"Based on random choice or personal whim, rather than any reason or system."`. He goes on to define his "personal whim": `"structural declarations first, followed by text declarations, followed by background declarations, and so on"`.

Comment: @thirtydot: "personal whim" would suggest the resulting application has a choice at _arbitrarily_ sorting - it doesn't because it will be programmed with `reason` as a `system`. Besides my initial comment was a quip at the wording, not to declare the question didn't make sense - or anything else for that matter. Thanks for your concern.

Comment: @Mr. Disappointment Most systems accept input.

Comment: @Alin Purcaru: _Arbitrary input_?

Comment: @Mr. Disappointment User defined. Maybe his wording was inappropriate when he said 'arbitrary'. He actually mean to say an order defined by him.

Comment: I already make sure to order my properties the way I want right from the get-go but... an automated tool would be great.

Comment: The tool needs to cope with situations where multiple properties effect the same thing, eg {border:1px solid black; border-top:0px;}, also ordering of declarations within file (later declarations can override earlier ones, subject to browser's scope/priority logic.

Comment: @Emyr: I can't speak for others, but for what i want personally i don't think that's an issue. I would just want it to 'dumbly' put the property declarations in the order that i've specified; i can handle the actual logic of overrides and cascading and everything else myself.

Comment: @kine: how well formed is your CSS? I could likely put together a C# snippet that'd sort it, based on your order, assuming I didn't have to  get real crazy parsing.

Comment: @sixlettervariables: I'd say it is fairly well-formed, but you don't have to do that. I was hoping there was just some tool that i had overlooked. Thanks though :)

Answer (score 2):

You could maybe look into http://www.codebeautifier.com/. There are a bunch of options you could choose from...

[image: screen shot]

... but that doesn't quite fit what you're looking for. There is also the option of defining your own template...

[image: screen shot 2]

... however, I don't quite know how it works. I hope this is helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You may find that you are able to do this through a project like [sass](http://sass-lang.com/).