# Eclipse: auto sort properties of a block

Tags: css, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I have the following block in css:

```
#id {
     font-size: 15px;
     color: #000;
     background-color: #fff;
}
```

Now I want Eclipse to automatically sort the properties of that block alphabetically:

```
#id {
     background-color: #fff;
     color: #000;
     font-size: 15px;
}
```

Is there a way to achive this inside Eclipse? I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5566457/sorting-css-properties-into-an-arbitrary-order), but there are only answers with external tools.

Answer (score 2):

I just know about

http://www.stateofflow.com/projects/2/sortit

with which you can select the line you want to sort.

Comment: But this isn't not really auto magic as PEP8 for Python in the PyDev editor